# How to use a file of different name while using render @collection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render, partial

Rails saves us an `each` loop by letting us directly pass the collection variables to `render` method like following:

```
<%= render @products %>
```

By default, it will look for a file named **_product.html.erb**, and render it for each single item in `@products` collection. For somehow, the file has been named as **_custom_product.html.erb**, now how to tell `render` method to render a file of name other than the standard **_product.html.erb**?

Comment: Will this `<%= render partial: "custom_product", collection: @products %>` work?

Comment: @Pavan No, it doesn't work. It says undefined variable `product` in _custom_product.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go either way:

To access your products via `product` local variable in the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "custom_product", collection: @products, as: :product %>
```

Or via `custom_product` in the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "custom_product", collection: @products %>
```

Comment: You can also try to use `<%= render partial: "custom_product", collection: @products %>` and access `custom_product` local variable. Not sure that it would work but you can give it a try, I'll this to the answer if it would.

Comment: It works too, but I'd prefer `as: :product`. Writing `custom_product` would be redundant, but may add readability.